# I have problems to insert data into my mysql Database using Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, insert

Can anyone Tell how can I modify my code so I can save data in my Database. 

My code is:

```
private Class nextPage;
@OnEvent(component="submitButton")
Object onSubmitFromSubmitButton()
{

    String flag="";
    String jndiname="jdbc/TestDB";
    DataSource dataSource=null;
    try{
        dataSource=(DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/" + jndiname);
        Connection con=dataSource.getConnection();
        Statement stm=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery("insert into recenzii (numeRecenzor,nivelIncredere,idHotel,recenzie) values (?,?,?,?)");



        ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();
        while(rs.next())
            {
              rs.getString("numeRecenzor");
              rs.getString("recenzie");
              rs.getInt("nivelIncredere");
              rs.getInt("idHotel");

            }

    }catch (Exception e){flag+=e.toString();}
    if (dataSource!=null)
        flag+=" succes";
System.out.println("Datele au fost trimise cu succes! "+flag);
    return nextPage;
}
}
```

I tried to put ExecuteUpdate or Execute instead of ExecuteQuery but I got some errors on the code that says it can't convert type int to ResultSet. I am new to this so I would appreciate if anyone could tell me what to modify. 
 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ResultSet object is used to retrieve data from database.
If you want to insert data, you can either supply the data to insert within the query and call stm.executeUpdate("insert ...")
or you can use PreparedStatement (there are more options, but these are easiest).

You may want to try something similar to this:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("insert into recenzii (numeRecenzor,nivelIncredere,idHotel,recenzie) values (?,?,?,?)");
preparedStatement.setString(1, "val1");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "val2");
preparedStatement.setInt(3, 3);
preparedStatement.setInt(4, 4);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I replace my code from ResultSet with yours, but nothing happened. I have a bean edit form in my application and when i push the button SUBMIT  I want to save the data from there to my database. Thank you for your answer